# Hibernate calling setter method

Tags: hibernate, merge

When I change a value in an inputtext field(which is populated from a db) and then merge, hibernate is doing something that I am not understanding.

Let's say the input text field is already populated with the string "New York".
When I go to change it to say "Boston", this is the order the getter and setter methods are being called in:
 PROPERTY GET: New York
 PROPERTY GET: New York
 PROPERTY SET: Boston
 PROPERTY SET: New York

It does not change the value to Boston and keeps the value as New York. This is the only input text field which references this field from the db.

Here are my setter and getters:

```
@Column(name = "City", length = 32)
public String getCity() {
    System.out.println("PROPERTY GET: " + city);
    return this.city;
}
public void setCity(String city) {
    System.out.println("PROPERTY SET: " + city);
    this.city = city;
}
```

Any idea why this would be happening?

Comment: We need to see the code calling the getter and setter in order to help you.

Comment: I can not say the exact answer observing this code.But may be your code is fetching the data (somewhere in the code) from database after you set the value to "Boston".Can you check the all occurrence in the setCity(String city) method in the project?

Comment: Hi. I actually figured it out. The screen I am working on is quite large and there were 2 areas where city was an input text field. I went to change the first input city. But because of the order in which the setters and getter were called caused, the value for city was set back to it original value from the other input text field...so any change made was being overriden by the original value since there were 2 input text fields mapped to the same field in the db